# java -verbose does not give a file location for every class

Tags: java, websphere, verbose

We are trying to debug some mean classloader issues with our WAS (Websphere Application Server) instance.

For this we provided the option -verbose:class in order to see which class WAS is loading where from.

For most classes we get output like

```
Loading class <some class> from <some jar file>
```

But for some classes (including the one causing problems) only

```
Loading class <some class>
```

gets printed.

Where is do these come from? Get they loaded straight from hell or why is IBM protecting their real identity?

Update:
The class we are looking for is javax.xml.ws.Service which should really come from a rt.jar (we are getting a java.lang.VerifyError on it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in which files are read by the JVM, you could use operating system tools like strace, dtrace, or lsof to observe the files read by a process. Though that won't tell you which classes where loaded from that file.

Are you aware of the [IBM JDK Diagnostics Guide?](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp) It contains a chapter "Class-loader diagnostics".

Comment: The Diagnostic Guide looks helpful. I'll try this for a start http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/tools/class_load_runtime.html

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the class you want to load does not come from an jar? Maybe it's generated on the fly? The name of the class might contain a hint ...

Comment: See the updated question. The class really SHOULD come from rt.jar but according to this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1d21c32446358cb338625720d0047ff40 that fact should really appear in the logs

Answer (score 2):

If the output looks like

```
[Loaded $Proxy2 by instance of java.lang.reflect.Proxy]
```

... then your classes are autogenerated

Comment: But a class can be generated on demand and the output looks differently.

Comment: Right, the case is however the same - the class is not from particular jar file

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't match our case, we see simple 'Loaded <class name>' without any further information